# Relation between the support of spectral measure and proportionality of the identity operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

Can someone tell me if the following is true.

Let A be a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, and let $P_A$ be the projection valued measure (spectral measure) obtained from the spectral theorem, such that

$A=\int t\ dP_A(t)$

How do I show that

$A=\lambda I$  $\ \ \ $  $\Leftrightarrow$ $\ \ \ $ $\text{supp}P_A=\{\lambda\}$

I have a strong feeling that it is true. I think one direction is clear due to the definition of the spectral measure, since it is defined on the Borel algebra of the spectrum of A. But for the other direction I don't know what to do?

Comment: **Hints.** What is $P_A(\{\lambda\})$? What is the value of the spectral integral $\int\lambda dP_A$? Is it equal to $A$ ? Then use the uniqueness of the spectral measure.

Comment: Well $P_A(\{\lambda\}=I$ if the support is $\{\lambda\}$, and by construction the integral is equal to $A$. But I cannot see why $\int t\, dP_A(t)=I$?? (i can see that I made a bad choice of name for the variable in the integral in my forst post since $\lambda$ is fixed.

Comment: Check the definition of the spectral integral for step-functions. $\int\lambda dP_A=\lambda I$

Comment: This is why I commented on the bad choice of variable name. Because I do know that $\int\lambda\,dP_A(t)=\lambda I$ but i do not know how to calculate $\int t\,dP_A(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A=\lambda I$, then
$$
          0= \left\|\int_{\sigma} (\mu-\lambda)dP_A(\mu)x\right\|^2=\int_{\sigma} |\mu-\lambda|^2d\|P_A(\mu)x\|^2,\;\;\; x\in H.
$$
If $d\|P_A(\mu)x\|^2$ has support outside of $\{\lambda\}$, then the above integral is non-zero. So $P_{A}(S)=P_{A}(S\cap\{\lambda\})$ for all Borel sets $S$ if $A=\lambda I$. Conversely, if $P_A$ is supported on $\{\lambda\}$, then $A=\int_{\sigma}\mu dP_A(\mu)= \lambda P_A\{\lambda\}=\lambda P_A(\mathbb{R})=\lambda I$.

Comment: How do you get $\int_\sigma \mu\,d P_A(\mu)=\lambda P_A\{\lambda\} $??

Comment: It is a nice answer though!!

Comment: If $P_A$ is supported on $\{\lambda\}$, then $\int_{\sigma} = \int_{\{\lambda\}}$.

Comment: Oh yes I see. Thanks!

Comment: Now I think I am comfusing myself again.. How do you get the equality 
$\left\Vert\int_\sigma \mu\,dP_A(\mu)x\right\Vert^2=\int_\sigma\vert\mu-\lambda\vert^2\,d\Vert P_A(\mu)x\Vert^2$??

Comment: @Simon : You're missing $-\lambda$ on the left side off your equation.

Comment: Wow, actually there were plenty of fails in my comment.. but i do not understand the eqaulity as you wrote it..

Comment: @Simon Do you know that $\|\int  f(\lambda)dP(\lambda)x\|^2 = \int |f(\lambda)|^2 d\|P(\lambda)x\|^2$ holds?

Comment: No.. That is the one I cannot figure out. I can get as far as
$\Vert \int f(\lambda)\,dP(\lambda)x\Vert^2=\langle \int f(\lambda)\,dP(\lambda)x,\int f(\lambda)\,dP(\lambda)x\rangle$ but if i start using the definition of the integral now, i end up with an integral with respect to the measure $P_{x,\int f(\lambda)\,dP(\lambda)x}$???

Comment: But I think I get that
$\langle \int f(\lambda)\,dP(\lambda)x,x\rangle=\int f(\lambda)d\Vert P(\lambda)x\Vert^2$ if that is right?

Comment: $\|f_1P(S_1)x+f_2P(S_2)+\cdots + f_n P(S_n)\|^2 = |f_1|^2\|P(S_1)x\|^2+\cdots+|f_n|^2\|P(S_n)x\|^2$ for any complex $f_k$ and any disjoint partition $\{ S_1,S_2,\cdots,S_n\}$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts can explain more why this show equal

Comment: @user89940 : The above shows $\|\int f(\lambda)dP(\lambda)x\|^2=\int |f(\lambda)|^2 d\|P(\lambda)x\|^2$.

Comment: but dont understand why

Comment: @user89940 You can view the two sides as integrals of simple functions.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts any book where i can show more about this equal?  thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are almost done. On the support of $P_A$, $t=\lambda$.